# Convert this equation from Matlab to TCL

Tags: matlab, tcl

I want to convert this equation from Matlab to TCL, Can anyone help.

```matlab
t = 2*pi*rand(n,1);
r = R*sqrt(rand(n,1));
x = x0 + r.*cos(t);
y = y0 + r.*sin(t);
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm "Evaluate an expression")? It is a a command that parses and evaluates infix/math expressions. The most important change you will have to do is that you'll have to put in `$` to get the values from variables, just like in the rest of Tcl.`expr` doesn't do assignments either, so you'll have to call it four times and assign the partial results to variables in Tcl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though there are many similarities, MATLAB has one key difference from Tcl: as well as single values, it can work on vectors, matrices and tensors. This makes translating your code a little more involved. (Apart from that, `=` maps to `set`, and expressions are computed with `expr`.)

```tcl
# Example initial parameters
set n 123
set R 321
set x0 456
set y0 654

# The translation of your code
set x {}
set y {}
set pi 3.1415927
for {set i 0} {$i < $n} {incr i} {
    set t [expr {2 * $pi * rand()}]
    set r [expr {$R * rand()}]
    lappend x [expr {$x0 + $r * cos($t)}]
    lappend y [expr {$y0 + $r * sin($t)}]
}
```

Note that shorter forms than this are possible through the use of an extension package such as VecTcl.

Comment: I assumed that the input parameters `R`, `x0` and `y0` were simple scalars.

Comment: Very thanks Donal for your time and effort.  With My Best Regards